ZAP: can attack or standard mode target sites outside of scope or not? Documentation and forum comments seems to contradict
Protected means: "Protected allows dangerous action on URLs defined in the Scope " so standard and attack allows dangerous actions outside of scope?
Could somebody clarify please how standard and attack mode effects scope? Can they ever attack sites outside of scope?
I didn't find any clear answer to this, only contradicting information like the cited one above

Per the docs: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/start/features/modes/
- **Safe** - no potentially dangerous operations permitted.
- **Protected** - you can only perform (potentially) dangerous actions on URLs in the scope.
- **Standard** - does not restrict anything.
- **ATTACK** - new nodes that are in scope are actively scanned as soon as they are discovered.


Could somebody clarify please how standard and attack mode effects scope?

The mode doesn't impact the scope, the scope impacts the actions you can carryout in a given mode.

Can they ever attack sites outside of scope?

Yes in Standard mode if you do not have a scope set, or if you do not choose "Only in-scope" in the various tools.
https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/start/features/scope/

The Scope is the set of URLs you are testing, and is defined by the Contexts you have specified.


By default nothing is in scope.

You can define multiple Contexts and select whether or not they should be considered "In Scope", by default they are.

thank you. So if I launch ZAP, and I paste an URL and press attack (so the default standard mode has not been changed) will it attack sites outside of the scope? So I have to go to the scope settings manually before I press attack on an URL?
